# How do I fix error " 'UIPopoverController' is deprecated"?

Tags: ios, deprecated, uipopovercontroller

Updating an old iOS program. Getting this error message:

> 'UIPopoverController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIPopoverController is deprecated. Popovers are now implemented as UIViewController presentations. Use a modal presentation style of UIModalPresentationPopover and UIPopoverPresentationController.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SubstitutableDetailViewController
- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
- (void)invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
@end

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate> {

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController;    
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;    
    UIBarButtonItem *rootPopoverButtonItem;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *rootPopoverButtonItem;

- (void) didSelectMenuItem:(NSNotification *) notification;
@end
```

Thanks in advance for any help,
Greg

Comment: See [Displaying Transient Content in a Popover](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_transient_content_in_a_popover). That’s in Swift, but the idea is the same in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks again Greg

Comment: Use smth like that for init and show:

 ModalViewController *pop= [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
 pop.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
 pop.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
 pop.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = myButton.frame;
 [self presentViewController:pop animated:YES completion:nil];
for dismiss:

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];